# Large data - how to scale large TCP transmissions across many parties

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, tcp, boost-asio

What is the best way to send large data over TCP, consider the following case:

I have 64 identical software running - multi-core, thread pool executing using boost asio.

Any copy of the software can decide to send messages (2mb). When they decide to send the message, they would send it to all 63 of the software in the network.

Also, at any time, multiple software can decide to send at the same time (up to 64 of them), so this means my software can receive 64 messages at the same time from 64 TCP sockets with single messages up to 2MB each. This also means I can decide to send 2MB of data to other 64 computers at the same time.

I currently call boost asio sync_write on all 64 sockets. And this can happen concurrently on all other 63 computers.

On the read side, all the sockets are doing async_read (1 read for the size of the entire message), and its a multi core processor (16 core).

All the async_read and async_write are using boost asio (so thread pool)

My problem is that I got two issues:

1. I was calling async_write before another async_write on the same socket has completed. I caught the error and I am thinking about either using sync write or a queue - can anyone advise on this?
2. I get error messages such as:
   21 resets received for embryonic SYN_RECV sockets
   205 packets pruned from receive queue because of socket buffer overrun

So I tuned the socket buffer size up, and now the issue is gone. However, I want to know how I can mechanize this so they can handle it better? I am sure I am not the only person that is sending 2MB messages, so how do other people handle this using boost asio?

what would be a better software architecture in this case?

Comment: TCP maintains a connection between exactly two hosts. For each host to maintain a TCP connection to every other host would require a total of 2016 (`64*63/2`) TCP connections on the network, and that is simply crazy (even iBGP, which requires a full mesh of TCP connections has mitigations, like route reflectors and confederations, to reduce the number of TCP connections required). There are several other way to accomplish this. Are you required to use TCP?

Comment: Between two endpoints, not hosts.  I read the OP as there being 64 endpoints on the network in total.

Comment: Do not use sync write. Use a queue.

Comment: You could use a [`strand`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/strands.html) or implement a queue with locking.

Comment: using a queue is part of the plan. however, does anyone know why I get pruned packets. 2016 connection isnt a problem, as they are p2p network so each software would only have 63 connections - which is fine. I just don't understand, why we are getting pruned receive queue

Comment: Sounds like a case for multicast groups. I.e. UDP

Comment: If you have "pruned packages" (that's not a term, by the way) you'll have to show all relevant code. Even then, hardware could be at fault (some hardware misbehaves with mismatched jumbo frame support etc.)

Comment: 1. pruned is a verbatim copy from the kernle error message

Comment: 2. UDP cannot be used. too big of data size - and they must arrive in order.